# Field 'id' expected a number but got <Salary: : - Claude maniragaba>

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to enable edit when hr state of change is approved

```
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        salary = Salary.objects.filter(id=obj).first()
        if obj.hr_state == 'request-change-approved' and request.user.user_role.position.code == 'HRM':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: id=obj_id should work if I'm not wrong

Comment: if object is `None' what do you expect to get?

Comment: @NikitaZhuikov actualu obj.id return NoneType but i want to check if obj is not None and hr_state is 'request-change-approved' when i click to the object in changelist

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the salary with

```
id=obj.id
```

instead of comparing with the whole object instance.

By the way the id is only None when the url called with a empty obj , else it will contain an object so don't worry about the None(i just read the comments so )